# Why value of 'echo $$' is different from pid of the process?

Tags: shell

it's my code.

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    system("echo $$");
    return 0;
}


$ ./a.out &
[1] 29227
$ 29228

$ ./a.out &
[1] 29107
$ 29108
```

and result is above.

why it's different each other?

Comment: Looks like `system()` creates a new child process.

Comment: because your call to `system()` is creating a new process. As an alternate solution, some shells will honor $PPID, but once you start nesting processes it can be a trick to get the right PID. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `system()` the OS spins (see man fork, also man execl) a new process a copy of your original process. This process then loads the new program that you wanted (shell in this case) which prints its pid. Therefore they differ.

Comment: but then how can i expand my argument in echo command?
char* args[]={"/bin/echo","-e","$$");
execv(args[0],args);

doesn't work

Comment: That's an interesting question and made me double check system(), thanks! Here it says: "system()  executes  a  command  specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c command", so a shell is spun and "$$" is a shell construct. When you run /bin/echo directly, you are skipping the shell's interpretation of "$$"